# Modificar existencias

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, webforms

Tengo una base de datos en sql server donde tengo las tablas productos, compra, ventas y en visual estudio cada una de estas tablas tiene su ventana para ser trabajado sus datos. Tengo procedimientos para insertar, eliminar y actualizar.

Quiero saber como hago para modificar la existencia viendo que esta en la tabla productos y la cantidad que se le restara esta en la tabla ventas. 
Muchas Gracias de Antemano.

Acá el procedimiento de agregar o actualizar

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[ProductosCreateOrUpdate]
@id int,
@descripcion varchar(100),
@idmarca int,
@idcategoria int,
@precioA int,
@precioB int,
@precioC int,
@precioD int
AS
If(@id=0)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS(descripcion, idMarca, idCateg,precioA,precioB,
    precioC,PrecioD)
    VALUES (@descripcion, @idmarca, @idcategoria, @precioA, @precioB,
    @precioC, @PrecioD)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    UPDATE PRODUCTOS
    SET
    descripcion = @descripcion,
    idMarca= @idmarca, 
    idCateg=@idcategoria,
    precioA=@precioA,
    precioB=@precioB,
    precioC=@precioC,
    PrecioD=@PrecioD
    WHERE id_prod = @id
    END
```

El de ventas es basicamente lo mismo se los dejo por si acaso

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[VentasCreateOrUpdate]
@numventa int,
@cliente varchar(50),
@fecha datetime,
@cantidad int,
@id_producto int,
@p_unitario int,
@p_total int
AS
If(@numventa=0)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO VENTAS(cliente, fecha, cantidad, id_producto, precio_unitario,precio_total)
    VALUES (@cliente, @fecha, @cantidad, @id_producto, @p_unitario,@p_total)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
    UPDATE VENTAS
    SET
    cliente = @cliente,
    fecha= @fecha, 
    cantidad=@cantidad,
    id_producto=@id_producto,
    precio_unitario=@p_unitario,
    precio_total=@p_total   
    WHERE numfactura= @numventa
    END
```

les dejo las relaciones

[image: Diagrama de relacion]

y en la programacion de del boton agregar en la venta tengo esto:

```
protected void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)

                cn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("VentasCreateOrUpdate", cn);
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numventa", (hfVentaID.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(hfVentaID.Value)));
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cliente", txtCliente.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", DateTime.Parse(txtFecha.Text.Trim()));
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantidad", txtCantidad.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_producto", ddlDescripcion.Text.Trim());
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_unitario", Convert.ToInt32(txtPrecioU.Text.Trim()));
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_total", Convert.ToInt32(txtPrecioT.Text.Trim()));

            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            string numventa = hfVentaID.Value;
            clear();


            if (numventa == "")
                lblSuccesseMessage.Text = "Agregado Correctamente";
            else
                lblSuccesseMessage.Text = "Modificado Correctamente";

            FillGridView();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Para restas existencias no usas ninguno de los dos procedures que has mencionado, ya que se trata de una operacion puntual sobre un campo de la tabla `productos` aplicando un where en base al id

Entonces la operacion quedaria algo como esto

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>"))
{
    conn.Open();

    string query = "UPDATE Productos SET stock = stock - @cantventa WHERE idproducto = @idproducto";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cantventa", Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idproducto", Convert.ToInt32(txtProductoId.Text));

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Puse directo el `UPDATE` para que quede claro la operacion, como veras son solo dos parametros la cantidad que quieres restar del producto ante una baja en el stock y el id del producto al cual afectar

**Nota:** Me parecio raro que uses `ddlDescripcion.Text` para definir un parametro de id de productos, porque se supone que el id debe ser numerico no un string o texto

Comment: Enitiendo, pero debería agregar esta linea al procedure, o hacerlo directamente en la programacion del boton?, Oh si olvide convertir a entero el ddlDescripcion

Comment: si lo necesitas podrias crear un procedure separado para actualizar el stock, pero no puedes ponerlo con los procedures existentes que nos mencioans porque son operaciones que no tienen relacion

Comment: Y a la hora de implementarlo en c#  donde lo pongo en el botón de agregar?

Comment: Ese codigo lo deberias poner despeus de crear la venta. Pero no recomiendo como lo realizas que unes el crear y el update en un unico proceso, ya que el crear agregara stock, pero el update puede que agregue o quite, las ventas se crean o elimina no se actualizan, asi tienes una operacion de agregar y otra de quitar stock al productos